# Example of surjective function without right-inverse (without AoC)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse, axiom-of-choice

As I understand from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463045/axiom-of-choice-and-right-inverse), without the axiom of choice, we can have surjective functions without right-inverse. Is that correct? Is there any such example of a surjective function where we need to use the AoC to prove the existence of the right-inverse?

Comment: Could you describe your well-ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ in a bit more detail? (Hint: you can't do it in plain old ZF.)

Comment: From your hint, of course the well-ordering is equivalent to AoC, so I removed that part from my question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485267/ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383312/ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726611/ probably a few more. There's a lot more about well orders of the reals, though.

Comment: What function exactly would be such an example?

Comment: Mapping each sequence of reals to its range; mapping each subset of $\Bbb R$ which is well-ordered (in the natural order) to its order type.

Comment: Is difference between highest and lowest element of the sequence meant with range or image of the sequence?

Comment: Range as in the set of reals that appear in that sequence. A sequence, after all, is nothing but a function.

Comment: It is not quite true that without AoC you can have surjective functions without right inverses. What is true is that you cannot always prove that a right inverse **must** exist. But to prove the existence of a surjective function without a right inverse, you have to go farther: you have to add an axiom that contradicts the AoC. If the AoC is known to be false, then you can use any counter-example to the AoC to construct a surjective map without right inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments: Let $S$ be the set of all sequences $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $T = \{Im(f)| f\in S\}$. Then the function $\phi: S \to T$ with $\phi(f)=Im(f)$ is surjective by definition. In order to define the right-inverse of $\phi$ for a given $t \in T$, you need to assign an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to every real number in $t$. For this, you need the axiom of choice.